# VB 6.0 - System.Uri.EscapeDataString in VB 6

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I recently made an app in VB 2010 and in order to make it independent of the .Net Framework, I begun remaking the app in VB 6.0. There's supposed to be a button on the form that, when pressed, opens the default email client. Then it opens a new email and copies into its body the text generated by the application on a Textbox. The problem with it is that the copied text in the body gets pasted with the wrong encoding and completely different from how it's supposed to be. I also encountered that problem in VB 2010 but I was able to fix this by using System.Uri.EscapeDataString like this

```
Process.Start("mailto:test@email.com?subject= &body=" & System.Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBox1.Text))
```

Is there a way to do something like this in vb 6.0 ?

```
ShellExecute Me.hwnd, "open", "mailto:test@email.com?subject= &body=" & NoonText.Text, _
                 vbNullString, vbNullString, 1
```

P.S I've tried URL Encoding it but wherever there are supposed to be spaces, crosses ("+") are pasted instead.

Comment: Why convert back to VB6? Do you have a time machine?

Comment: *"I recently made an app in VB 2010 and in order to make it independent of the .Net Framework, I begun remaking the app in VB 6.0."* That sounds like a particularly bad idea. Please reconsider. The VB6 IDE is unsupported since April 8, 2008.

Comment: A .Net app can have its own local version of the .Net framework, keeping the app completely independent of system-wide updates. There's no reason to worry about being dependent on the .Net framework, especially if you are replacing with a dependency on the VB6 runtime. At the moment the VB6 runtime is fully supported as part of Windows, but eventually it could be dropped...

Answer (score 0):

OK. Here's the bulk of the code that *should* behave like `System.Uri.EscapeUriString` and `System.Uri.EscapeDataString` using, respectively, the methods named `EscapeURI()` and `EscapeURIData()` provided in the listing below. Like any random piece of code, consider it's provided as is and thoroughly test it before you ever consider using it.

I'm providing the code for two (2) reasons:

1. Although your motives are questionable, as people with more reputation than me have rightly noted, there may arise a case where somebody will be confronted with the same question but for different reasons. The answer to your problem remains *"Don't do it"*, but I still consider the technical question, per se, not any less valid and on topic.
2. Hopefully, with this answer you'll realize it's utterly pointless to reinvent the wheel. VB.NET was created as the successor of VB6, with among other objectives to provide means to build solutions for current, "real-world" problems all the while using less code, so it's more manageable and easier to maintain. Also, the VB6 runtime (MSVBVM60.DLL) as a dependency is more problematic than the .NET Framework simply because its support is no longer guaranteed.

So, here's the code. It's basically an implementation of character escaping as described in RFC 3986 on top of a UTF-8 encoding routine. The code is not optimized but commented so as to be easy to understand. Also, it *does not* support Internationalized Domain Names (RFC 3987).

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (dest As Any, src As Any, ByVal cb As Long)

Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long _
) As Long

Private Declare Function WideCharToMultiByte Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cbMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpDefaultChar As Long, _
    ByVal lpUsedDefaultChar As Long _
) As Long

Private Enum VbStrConv2
    vbUpperCase = VbStrConv.vbUpperCase
    vbLowerCase = VbStrConv.vbLowerCase
    vbProperCase = VbStrConv.vbProperCase
    vbWide = VbStrConv.vbWide
    vbNarrow = VbStrConv.vbNarrow
    vbHiragana = VbStrConv.vbHiragana
    vbUnicode = VbStrConv.vbUnicode
    vbFromUnicode = VbStrConv.vbFromUnicode
    vbUTF8 = &H100&
    vbFromUTF8 = &H200&
End Enum

Private Const CP_ACP        As Long = 0          ' Default ANSI code page.
Private Const CP_UTF8       As Long = 65001      ' UTF8.
Private Const CP_UTF16_LE   As Long = 1200       ' UTF16 - little endian.
Private Const CP_UTF16_BE   As Long = 1201       ' UTF16 - big endian.
Private Const CP_UTF32_LE   As Long = 12000      ' UTF32 - little endian.
Private Const CP_UTF32_BE   As Long = 12001      ' UTF32 - big endian.

Public Function EscapeURI(ByVal URI As String, Optional ByVal JSCompatible As Boolean = False) As String
' As per "RFC 1738: Uniform Resource Locators (URL) specification"
' 21-06-2010: Modified to conform to "RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax"
Dim i As Long
Dim bAnsi() As Byte
Dim iAscii As Integer
Dim sEscapedUri As String
    bAnsi = StrConv2(URI, VbStrConv2.vbUTF8)
    sEscapedUri = vbNullString
    For i = LBound(bAnsi) To UBound(bAnsi)
        iAscii = bAnsi(i)
        Select Case iAscii
            ' ASCII control caracters, always escape
            Case 0 To 31, 127
                If iAscii < 16 Then
                    sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & "%0" & Hex$(iAscii)
                Else
                    sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
                End If
            ' Non-ASCII characters, always escape
            Case 128 To 255
                sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
            ' Reserved characters, don't escape with an URI
            ' RFC 3986 section 2.2 Reserved Characters (January 2005)
            '     !   #   $   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]
            Case 33, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 47, 58, 59, 61, 63, 64, 91, 93
                If JSCompatible Then
                    Select Case iAscii
                        '     [   ]
                        Case 91, 93
                            ' ECMAScript's encodeURI() escapes those
                            ' (since IPv6, hosts can be e.g. [::1/128] so we want to preserve them unescaped)
                            sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
                        Case Else
                            sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & Chr$(iAscii)
                    End Select
                Else
                    sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & Chr$(iAscii)
                End If
            ' Unreserved characters, never escape
            ' RFC 3986 section 2.3 Unreserved Characters (January 2005)
            '     -   .   0 ... 9   A ... Z   a .... z   _   ~
            Case 45, 46, 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 95, 126
                sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & Chr$(iAscii)
            ' Unsafe characters, always escape
            '     "   %   <   >   \   ^   `   {    |    }
            Case 34, 37, 60, 62, 92, 94, 96, 123, 124, 125
                sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
            ' Space, escaped
            Case 32
                sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & "%20"
            Case Else
                sEscapedUri = sEscapedUri & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
        End Select
    Next i
    EscapeURI = sEscapedUri
End Function

Public Function EscapeURIData(ByVal URIData As String, Optional ByVal JSCompatible As Boolean = False) As String
' As per "RFC 1738: Uniform Resource Locators (URL) specification"
' 21-06-2010: Modified to conform to "RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax"
Dim i As Long
Dim bAnsi() As Byte
Dim iAscii As Integer
Dim sEscapedData As String
    bAnsi = StrConv2(URIData, VbStrConv2.vbUTF8)
    sEscapedData = vbNullString
    For i = LBound(bAnsi) To UBound(bAnsi)
        iAscii = bAnsi(i)
        Select Case iAscii
            ' ASCII control caracters, always escape
            Case 0 To 31, 127
                If iAscii < 16 Then
                    sEscapedData = sEscapedData & "%0" & Hex$(iAscii)
                Else
                    sEscapedData = sEscapedData & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
                End If
            ' Non-ASCII characters, always escape
            Case 128 To 255
                sEscapedData = sEscapedData & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
            ' Reserved characters, always escape when treated as data
            ' RFC 3986 section 2.2 Reserved Characters (January 2005)
            '     !   #   $   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]
            Case 33, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 47, 58, 59, 61, 63, 64, 91, 93
                If JSCompatible Then
                    Select Case iAscii
                        '     !   '   (   )   *
                        Case 33, 39, 40, 41, 42
                            ' ECMAScript's encodeURIComponent() doesn't escape those
                            sEscapedData = sEscapedData & Chr$(iAscii)
                        Case Else
                            sEscapedData = sEscapedData & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
                    End Select
                Else
                    sEscapedData = sEscapedData & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
                End If
            ' Unreserved characters, never escape
            ' RFC 3986 section 2.3 Unreserved Characters (January 2005)
            '     -   .   0 ... 9   A ... Z   a .... z   _   ~
            Case 45, 46, 48 To 57, 65 To 90, 97 To 122, 95, 126
                sEscapedData = sEscapedData & Chr$(iAscii)
            ' Unsafe characters, always escape
            '     "   %   <   >   \   ^   `   {    |    }
            Case 34, 37, 60, 62, 92, 94, 96, 123, 124, 125
                sEscapedData = sEscapedData & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
            ' Space, escaped
            Case 32
                sEscapedData = sEscapedData & "%20"
            Case Else
                sEscapedData = sEscapedData & "%" & Hex$(iAscii)
        End Select
    Next i
    EscapeURIData = sEscapedData
End Function

'
' Utilities
'

Private Function StrConv2(Expr As Variant, Conversion As VbStrConv2, Optional LocaleID As Long = 0)
Const METHOD_NAME = "StrConv2"
Dim sExpr As String, arr_bytInput() As Byte, lLBound As Long
    Select Case Conversion
        Case VbStrConv2.vbUTF8 ' LocaleID not used (no case changing, no code page mapping)
            Dim lInputChars As Long
            Dim lOutputBytes As Long, arr_bytOutputBytes() As Byte
            ' Expected input: Unicode (UCS-2)
            Select Case VarType(Expr)
                Case vbString
                    sExpr = CStr(Expr)
                    ' Get length of input, in *characters*
                    lInputChars = Len(sExpr)
                    ' Copy input string as-is
                    arr_bytInput = sExpr
                Case (vbArray + vbByte)
                    ' Get length of input, in *characters*
                    lInputChars = (UBound(Expr) - LBound(Expr) + 1) \ 2
                    ' Copy array (same type)
                    arr_bytInput = Expr
                Case Else
                    Err.Raise 13, METHOD_NAME, "Expr: Type mismatch (in " & METHOD_NAME & "())"
            End Select
            ' Get size of output strings, in *bytes*
            lOutputBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, VarPtr(arr_bytInput(0)), lInputChars, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            ' Size appropriately
            ReDim arr_bytOutputBytes(lOutputBytes - 1)
            ' Second call
            lOutputBytes = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, VarPtr(arr_bytInput(0)), lInputChars, VarPtr(arr_bytOutputBytes(0)), lOutputBytes, 0, 0)
            ' Return as array of bytes
            StrConv2 = arr_bytOutputBytes
        Case VbStrConv2.vbFromUTF8 ' LocaleID not used (no case changing, no code page mapping)
            Dim lInputBytes As Long
            Dim lOutputChars As Long, arr_bytOutputChars() As Byte
            ' Expected input: UTF-8
            Select Case VarType(Expr)
                Case vbString
                    arr_bytInput = StrConv(Expr, vbFromUnicode)
                    ' Get length of input, in *bytes*
                    lInputBytes = (UBound(arr_bytInput) - LBound(arr_bytInput) + 1)
                Case (vbArray + vbByte)
                    ' Copy array (same type)
                    arr_bytInput = Expr
                    ' Get length of input, in *bytes*
                    lInputBytes = (UBound(arr_bytInput) - LBound(arr_bytInput) + 1)
                Case Else
                    Err.Raise 13, METHOD_NAME, "Expr: Type mismatch (in " & METHOD_NAME & "())"
            End Select
            ' Get size of output strings, in *chars*
            lOutputChars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, VarPtr(arr_bytInput(0)), lInputBytes, 0, 0)
            ' Size appropriately
            ReDim arr_bytOutputChars(lOutputChars * 2 - 1)
            ' Second call
            lOutputChars = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, VarPtr(arr_bytInput(0)), lInputBytes, VarPtr(arr_bytOutputChars(0)), lOutputChars)
            ' Return as string
            sExpr = arr_bytOutputChars
            StrConv2 = Left$(sExpr, lOutputChars)
        Case Else
            StrConv2 = StrConv(Expr, Conversion, LocaleID)
    End Select
End Function
```